# Java - Overriding hashCode and toString

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, equals, tostring

When two objects have same value of `ele` in class A then those two objects are equal. So I have overridden toString and hashCode to return the object's `ele` (not considering the value of `s` anywhere).

```
public class A {
    private int ele;
    private String s;

    public int getEle() {
        return ele;
    }

    public void setEle(int ele) {
        this.ele = ele;
    }

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        return ele;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(ele);
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<A, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    A a1 = new A();
    a1.setEle(10);
    a1.setS("abc");

    A a2 = new A();
    a2.setEle(10);
    a2.setS("efg");

    map.put(a1, "val1");
    map.put(a2, "val2");

    System.out.println(map.get(a1));
    System.out.println(map.get(a2));

}
```

**Output:**

```
val1
val2
```

But if I put value of `a1` and `a2` in a map, I was expecting either `val1` or `val2` to be returned for both `map.get(a1)` and `map.get(a2)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, `a1` and `a2` have the same hash code, but they weren't considered equal because you didn't override `equals` to consider two `A` objects with the same `ele` to be equal.  A map will use `equals` to the final ruler on equality after it uses the hash code.  The map will place both objects in the same bucket, but because they aren't equal, it will keep both.

Override `equals` so that it returns `true` if the other object is an `A` and they both have the same `ele`.  Then you will see that `val2` will be returned for both `get` calls.

Comment: Oh ya.. My bad. I thought it uses toString to get the string representation and then compare

Comment: But I guess it uses a list when chaining. But I enter val1 first. But I get val2 for both. Why?

Comment: When you `put` `a2` into the map, the map considers it equal to `a1`, because `equals` returns `true`.  The map then _replaces_ the key-value pair (an `Entry`) that was there, `a1 -> "val1"`, with `a2` -> "val2".  Both your `get` calls will result in `equals` returning `true`, so the current value, `"val2"` is retrieved each time.

Comment: Historically, `HashMap` has always used a linked list of nodes that hash to the same bucket.  Starting in Java 8, `HashMap` switches over to a tree map-like structure when the number of entries in the bucket reaches a threshold.  My Java 8 source code indicates that this threshold is currently 8.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement equals() to take `ele` value into consideration when adding to a map, i.e.:

```
public class A {

    private int ele;
    private String s;

    public int getEle() {
        return ele;
    }

    public void setEle(int ele) {
        this.ele = ele;
    }

    public String getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public void setS(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        A a = (A) o;

        return ele == a.ele;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return ele;
    }
}
```

This will make you return only one value as you want.

Answer (score 0):

every time you use `new` keyword it makes a new `object` in `heap` Memory. So, `a1` and `a2` both are different Object in actual.

Please Refer this for more info about `new` keyword [What New keyword do Internally in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019754/what-does-the-new-keyword-actually-do-in-java-and-should-i-avoid-creating-new)