# In which package new operator is defined and declared in java?

Tags: java, class, package, new-operator

As in Java, everything is class. Is there a java file present for new keyword also? If yes, please tell the package name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019754/what-does-the-new-keyword-actually-do-in-java-and-should-i-avoid-creating-new

Comment: It's an *operator*. Do you also think you can find the `+` operator in a class?

Comment: No, idea about that '+' operator but i am talking about new operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As in Java, everything is class.

No, not necessarily.

> Is there a java file present for new keyword also?

No there isn't. Keywords and operators aren't classes, they are reserved words or symbols that are used in the language. They aren't objects.

`new` is an operator and keyword. There's no class for keywords such as `return`, `public`, etc. and no classes for the `+` operator either.

---

As for primitive wrapper classes such as: `Float, Double, Long, Boolean, Character, Byte, Short, Integer`, they are class forms of primitives that have more capabilities than their respective primitives and can be used in things like data structures, *but this is only applicable for primitives*. `new` is not a primitive.

Comment: Keyword like float, byte are having .java file files inside java/lang folder.

Comment: Wrapper classes are also type of classes which can be defined in java. So, there must be some code which defines the working of new operator?

Comment: No their isn't. @NickSilicon, wrapper classes are for *primitives*. `new` is not a primitive. `new` is a reserved keyword that has functions at the lower level, such as assembly where memory is allocated for a new 'object'.

Comment: Do all new operator in all programming language work in same exact way?

Comment: @NickSilicon Not sure what you mean by the exact same way. `new` in Java means a new object is created by allocating memory. It has the same concept in many languages, but say in Python, `new` is completely omitted when it comes to instantiation.

Comment: As you said new functions at assembly level so it means new functions in same way for all the programming language as assembly language is machine dependent.

Comment: @NickSilicon Not necessarily *exactly* the same but have much of the same functionality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123662/discussion-between-nick-silicon-and-andrew-l).