# How multiple objects can have the same name?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I don't know if this is a silly question or maybe it's comenscence but my question is  I'm creating a Linked List class which contains an add Method

```
public void addFirst(int data){
        node node = new node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
            tail = node;
            currentSize++;
        }
        else
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
        currentSize++;
    }
```

}
so when i use it like this:

```
public static void main(String argas[]){
Linkedlist list = new Linkedlist();
  
  list.addFirst(5)
  list.addFirst(10)
  list.addFirst(15)
  list.addFirst(20)
```

the node that contains 5 has the same name as the node contains 10 and the rest of nodes,
how does it works?

The complete code

```
public class LinkedList {
    class node {
        int data;
        node next;

        public node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            next = null;
        }
        public node(){
        }

    }
    private node head;
    private node tail;
    private int currentSize;
        public LinkedList (){
        head = null;
        currentSize = 0;
        }

        public void addFirst(int data){
            node node = new node(data);
            if (head == null) {
                head = node;
                tail = node;
                currentSize++;
            }
            else
            node.next = head;
            head = node;
            currentSize++;
        }
        public void addLast(int data){
            node node = new node(data);
            node tmp = new node();
            if (head == null) {
                head = node;
                tail = node;
                currentSize++;
                return;
            }
            tail.next = node;
            tail = node;
            currentSize++;
            return;
        }

        public void removeFirst(){
            if (head == null){
                return;
            }
            if (head == tail){
                head = tail = null;
                currentSize--;
            }
            else
            head = head.next;
            currentSize--;
        }

        public void removeLast(){
            if (head == null){
                return;
            }
            if (head == tail){
                head = tail = null;
                return;
            }
            else {
                node tmp = new node();
                tmp = head;
                while (tmp.next != tail){
                    tmp = tmp.next;
                }
                tmp.next = null;
                tail = tmp;
                currentSize--;
            }
        }


        public void printList(){
            node tmp = new node();
            tmp = head;

            while (tmp != null){
                System.out.println(tmp.data);
                tmp = tmp.next;
            }
        }

        public void size(){
            System.out.println((currentSize));
        }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _name_ here? Btw, you should work on your class naming: `node node` should be `Node node`, i.e. the class name should start with a capital letter to avoid confusion with variable names.

Comment: Another side note: you should also work on code formatting and ideally use curly braces even for one-statement blocks. Right now that else block of yours can make it hard to spot errors or the intent, i.e. would `head = node;` be intended to be inside the else block or not? (right now it isn't)

Comment: @Thomas    
 I mean : 
when we create a new node this's what happening
        Node node = new Node(data);
everytime we create a new node we create it with the name "node" 
how can this be possible

Comment: You must learn about `variable scopes` and `references` in Java. That will give you a lot of clarity

Comment: Honestly, the real answer here is: pick a good book on Java, and start reading slowly and carefully. This community is for specific questions on programming, it is not meant as replacement for you doing that *learning* part. Your request basically boils down to "please explain to me some fundamental concepts of programming languages".

Comment: For starters, you could read this question and the answers to it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019754/what-does-the-new-keyword-actually-do-in-java-and-should-i-avoid-creating-new

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks

Comment: And yes, you definitely want to learn about java naming practices. Class names go UpperCase, always. And you try very hard to not "shadow" names, like calling a class `node` , and then a field / variable `node` too.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the good suggestions in the above comments. However, for any other new learner coming here and looking for any answer, I am giving below the correction to be done in `addFirst()` method, you need to change other functions if you have not used blocks properly. Try to rename your class to `Node`, and so your source file to `Node.java`

```
public void addFirst(int data)
{
     node node = new node(data);
     if (head == null) 
     {
            //this is the first ever node, set the head & tail
            head = node;
            tail = node;
     }
     else
     {   
           //place the below lines of code together in a block
           node.next = head;
           head = node;
      }
     currentSize++;
}
```